# pgfplots requires more than expected xticklabels

Tags: pgfplots

the following code does what I want in terms of xticklabels, however, I do not understand why I had to insert 5 xticklabels instead of only three including a phantom-label to achieve my goal. Is there a more elegant, comprehensible way?

```
    \begin{document}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    grid=major, xmin=0, xmax=4,
    xticklabel style = {rotate=90, anchor=east},
    xticklabels = {0,\phantom{0},Chlor,Brom,Jod}
    ]
    \addplot[thick,dashed] coordinates { (0,20) (4,20) };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When setting `ticklabels` manually, you should also set `tick` values yourself so that you control their position as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this example, note that in the second picture, there are not `ticks` at `x=0` and `x=4`. If you want to leave a `tick` without `ticklabel` just leave an empty `,,` in your `ticklabels={...}`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    grid=major, xmin=0, xmax=4,
    xticklabel style = {rotate=90, anchor=east},
    xticklabels = {0,\phantom{0},Chlor,Brom,Jod}
    ]
    \addplot[thick,dashed] coordinates { (0,20) (4,20) };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    grid=major, xmin=0, xmax=4,
    xticklabel style = {rotate=90, anchor=east},
    xtick={1,2,3},
    xticklabels = {Chlor,Brom,Jod}
    ]
    \addplot[thick,dashed] coordinates { (0,20) (4,20) };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    grid=major, xmin=0, xmax=4,
    xticklabel style = {rotate=90, anchor=east},
    xtick={1,2,3},
    xticklabels = {Chlor,,Jod}
    ]
    \addplot[thick,dashed] coordinates { (0,20) (4,20) };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]